# Circumvent EVAL in SCHEME

Tags: scheme

Peter Norvig in PAIP says:

> in modern lisps...eval is used less often (in fact, in Scheme there is
> no eval at all). If you find yourself using eval, you are probably
> doing the wrong thing

What are some of the ways to circumvent using `eval` in scheme? Arent there case where `eval` is absolutely necessary?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are cases where `eval` is necessary, but they always involve advanced programs that do things like dynamically loading some code (eg, a servlet in a web server).  As for a way to "circumvent" using it -- that depends on the actual problem you're trying to solve, there's no magic solution to avoiding `eval` except for ... `eval`.

(BTW, my guess is that PAIP was written a long time ago, before `eval` was added to the Scheme Report.)

Comment: I am sorry I couldn't be more specific about what i wanted in the question. But whats interesting is that I always thought eval was always an integral part of Scheme. Anyway I hope I get to see more usage and 'abuses' of eval in CS G111. :)

Comment: Yes, `eval` *is* an integral part of Scheme, but it is only really needed in advanced cases.  The rule of thumb is: if you don't know the technical reasons that require you to use `eval`, then you *don't* need it.  (And this is a serious answer!)
In any case, yes, you'll have lots of `eval`ing in CSG111 if you're going to take it, and hopefully if you remember, ask me about it.

Answer (score 5):

He's wrong. Of course there is `eval` in Scheme.

Comment: Which scheme? I don't think r4rs required eval to be present at all.

Comment: @newacct PAIP came in 1992 and the R4RS didn't have eval. R5Rs came in 1998 and added eval, dynamic-wind and values :)

Answer (score 3):

You'll need `eval` in some very rare case. The case that comes into mind first is when you'll build program with a program and then execute it. This happens mainly with **genetic algorithm** for example. In this case you build a lot a randomized programs that you'll need to execute. Having `eval` in conjunction with code being data make lisp the easiest programming language to do genetic algorithm.

Having these properties comes at a great cost (in term of speed and size of your program) because you'll remove all possibility to do compile time optimization on the code that will be evaled and you must keep the full interpreter in your resulting binary.

As a result it is considered poor design to use `eval` when it can be avoided.

Answer (score 3):

The claim that Scheme has no `eval` is inaccurate at least for the most recent versions of the Scheme standard (R5RS and later).  Usually, what you want is a macro instead, which will generate code at compilation time.

It is true that `eval` should be avoided.  For starters, I've never seen a satisfactory definition of how should it behave, for example:

1. What environment expressions should be evaluated in when no environment is passed?
2. When you do pass in an environment, how do those work?  For example, the standards specify no way you can pre-bind a value in that environment object.

That said, I've worked with a Scheme application that uses `eval` to generate code dynamically at runtime for cases where the structure of the computation cannot be known at compilation time.  The intent has been to get the Scheme system to **compile** the code at runtime for performance reasons—and the difficulty is that there is no standard way to tell a Scheme system "compile this code."

It should go without saying also that `eval` can be a huge security risk.  You should never `eval` anything that doesn't have a huge wall of separation from user input.  Basically, if you want to use `eval` safely, you should be doing so in the context of the code-generation phase of a compiler-like system, after you've parsed some input (using a comprehensively defined grammar!).

Answer (score 1):

First, PAIP is written for Common Lisp, not Scheme, so I don't know that he'd say the same thing.  CL macros do much the same thing as `eval`, although at compile time instead of run time, and there's other things you could do.  If you'd show me an example of using `eval` in Common Lisp, I could try to come up with other methods of doing the same thing.

I'm not a Scheme programmer.  I can only speak from Norvig's perspective, as a Common Lisp programmer.  I don't think he was talking about Scheme, and I don't know if he knew or knows Scheme particularly well.

Second, Norvig says "you are probably doing the wrong thing" rather than "you're doing the wrong thing".  This implies that, for all he knows, there's times when `eval` is the correct thing to use.  In a language like C, I'd say the same thing about `goto`, although they're quite useful in some restricted circumstances, but most `goto` use is by people who don't know any better.

Comment: "I dont know if he knows Scheme particularly well". This statement is quite unbelievable. "there's times when eval is the correct thing to use". That was my second question. As practicing programmers, have you used eval?

Comment: Obviously, Norvig is extremely good at Common Lisp, having written a truly excellent book about it.  That doesn't apply to Scheme.  Would Stroustrup necessarily be a good authority on the best way to do something in Java or Objective-C?  That family of languages is no more disparate than the Lisp family including Common Lisp and Scheme.

Comment: hmmm he does implement scheme in lisp..oh well i dont know . but i would assume he lies at the "knows particularly well" spectrum.

Answer (score 0):

One use I've seen for 'eval' in scripting environments is to parameterize some code with runtime values.  for instance, in psuedo-C:

```
param = read_integer();
fn = eval("int lambda(int x) { 
            int param = " + to_string(param) + "; 
            return param*x; }");
```

I hope you find that really ugly.  String pasting to create code at runtime?  Ick.  In Scheme and other lexically scoped Lisps, you can make parameterized functions without using eval.

```
(define make-my-fn
  (lambda (param)
    (lambda (x)  (* param x)))

(let* ([ param  (read-integer) ]
       [ fn     (make-my-fn param ])
  ;; etc.
 )
```

Like was mentioned, dynamic code loading and such still need eval, but parameterized code and code composition can be produced with first class functions.

Answer (score -1):

You could write a scheme interpreter in scheme. Such is certainly possible, but it is not practical.

Granted, this is a general answer, as I have no used scheme, but it may help you nonetheless. :)

Comment: This is no where near the answer I wanted. : )