# Given the powerful macro system, are `quote` and `quasiquote` redundant in modern Scheme?

Tags: scheme, eval, racket, quotes

Modern Scheme (and its descendants like Racket) features a very powerful hygienic macro system.  It seems to me `quote` and `quasiquote` have lost their historical position in defining (unhygienic) macros (as is still done in Common Lisp if I do not mistake it) to the hygienic macros system.  Actually in the language report, `quote` and `quasiquote` are only presented as convenient ways of constructing data, particularly lists.  Indeed one can do without them, if she can bear the tediousness.  For example, `(quote (+ 1 2))` can be rewritten as `(list (quote +) 1 2)`, `(quasiquote (+ (unquote (- 2 1)) 2))` can be rewritten as `(list (quote +) (- 2 1) 2)`.

Now suppose we introduce a new primitive type for symbols into Scheme: an identifier starting with a capital letter is a symbol otherwise a variable.  So `X` means the symbol `x`, then the above examples can be written as `(list Plus 1 2)` and `(list Plus (- 2 1) 2)`.  (Let's assume that `Plus` represents the symbol `+`.)  Now can we say that `quote` and `quasiquote` are redundant?  Or do I miss something?

**Edit**:

1. `eval` seems still useful in some rare cases: [EVAL in SCHEME](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1044499/eval-in-scheme)
2. Clarified question.

Comment: You do realize that `(list '+ '1 '2)` is shorthand for `(list (quote +) (quote 1) (quote 2))`?

Comment: Yes, I know.  Forgot to desugar this part.

Comment: Rewriting `(quote (+ 1 2))` as `(list (quote +) (quote 1) (quote 2))` does not seem to reduce the need for `quote`.

Comment: @TerjeD.: Good point, question edited.

Comment: So you want `$x` to return the symbol `x`, while `x` by itself returns it's value. That functionality already exists as a special form called `quote`, and with `'x` as a shorthand syntax. (Yes, you can avoid the _name_ `quote`, but not the _concept_ `quote`.)

Comment: OK, that is a bad notation.  What if we provide a primitive type for symbols, say an identifier starting with a capital letter is a symbol, otherwise is a variable?

Comment: The capital letter convention would just be `quote` using yet another syntax. It would just be less general because it only applies to symbols.

Comment: @larsmans: Here syntax comes short.  What I am trying to say is that support the language offers a standalone type for symbols, whatever syntax chosen as long as it can not be confused with variables.  Do you see my point?

Comment: I think the capital letter syntax can be implemented in terms of `string->symbol` without using `quote`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your question is unclear.  It seems that you're asking whether there's some technical need for a quote, and if this is true, then your new `$` *is* just like a primitive `'`.  The convenience of quoting parenthesized forms was never strictly necessary, since you could always use just quoted symbols -- but this convenience is very important when you start talking about higher representation levels, where just a raw symbol-quote means that the representation explodes.  To see what I mean, the quotation of `(+ x 1)` becomes `(list '+ 'x 1)`, and the quotation of that becomes `(list 'list (list 'quote '+) (list 'quote 'x) 1)` -- this makes the advantage of the normal `quote` obvious...

As for `eval` being useful: it definitely is useful.  The main thing to realize about macros is that they transform static pieces of code -- and in fact most implementations will expand macros away as part of their compilation, and justified uses of `eval` are exactly the kind of things that depend on some dynamically generated input.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification and answer.  The question then is: what do we want this kind of higher representation for (except for constructing lists and vectors more conveniently), given that writing programs that write programs can be done using macros?

Comment: You're confusing macros with dynamic evaluation.  You *cannot* use macros to write programs dynamically.  Think about implementing a live REPL as the most obvious example of something that macros don't help you with.

Comment: OK, my poor phrasing.  I consider writing macros also writing *kinda* (meta-) programs.  But I see your point.  Thanks.

Comment: Yes, macros are functions that create code -- so they are meta in a non-kinda way.  But they do that statically, which is why they're unrelated to `eval`.  You could abuse `eval` to create macro-like things that build some code and evaluate it dynamically (this would have questionable value, BTW), but you cannot go the other way and use macros to implement an `eval`.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, `quote` is redundant, but you don't need the capital-letter convention. You can have `quote` followed by an identifier (symbol) produce a `string->symbol` expression with the string content of the symbol.

```
(quote x) => (string->symbol "x")
```